# SO Blogging caps

Tags: feature-request, self-answer, blogging

I think [Should I ask a question I know the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to/) suggests every user should have the ability to post "blog" questions.

[My answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to/45522#45522) suggests these self-answerable questions don't belong on SO (because it kind of looks like silly unprofitable gaming of the system - "I have a question.. OH LOOK, I CAN ANSWER IT!").

So I suggest something like the ability to post a "BLOG" question.  A "BLOG QUESTION" isn't really a question, its more of a personal diary entry of sorts.

In this helps make SO [more and more of an answer archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10092/why-do-you-help-in-stackoverflow/10155#10155) than it already is!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this, as long as you wait a while before posting your answer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it if you *don't* wait a while. OK, *I* make my answer CW when I do that. So as not to be rep whoring.

Answer (score 6):

A question is a question.  What matters to Stack Overflow users is not *who* answered it, but that it *has a good answer*.

If I slap a specific error message into Google, and a Stack Overflow question is the first result, and the answer solves my problem, do I really care who answered it or how soon?

Self-accepted answers do not stay at the top, like other accepted answers.  If somebody else has a better answer than you, it will be shown above your answer.  And if nobody else has a better answer than you, then it means that the answer will eventually be valuable to someone with the same question/problem.

Frankly, I would say that if people *want* to post blog-like content on SO (as long as the content can actually be framed as a *technical question*), and subsequently forfeit many of the intellectual property rights that they would enjoy by publishing it on their own blog, then why not let them?

The only time I would look down on this behaviour is if the "answer" is nothing more than a link to somebody's blog.  That's basically spam.  As long as the answer is complete, correct, and well-written, then both the question and answer belong on SO as much as anything else.

Answer (score 3):

> My answer suggests these self-answerable questions don't belong on SO

This I don't agree with at all. If you sort out a specific issue that is likely to happen to somebody else, too, I can see nothing wrong with posting the solution as a question / answer to SO - maybe even just to find out that there would have been a more elegant way :D

I see what you're getting at, but I find a good self-answered question all right and even worthy of some reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Then main reason why this is deemed acceptable is because there is a 2 day accept limit on your own answers.

The expected behavior is that the question asker should wait that 2 days, and see if anyone else can come up with a better answer than theirs, and thus gives future-question askers a better answer.

---

Honestly, asking questions isn't about whether you know the answer or not. Asking a question is simply trying to get **another** person's idea to what the answer is.

There are tons of examples of this. Optimization, Best-Practice questions, are all questions that the question asker might know the answer to, but they want someone else's opinion on the matter.

And going back to the topic on hand, if the asker doesn't believe that someone else's answer is valid, they can then post their own.